# Find most frequent lines and count them

Tags: bash, awk

How may I count the number of occurrences in let say in such list:

```
onion
apple
kiwi
orange
kiwi
orange
onion
kiwi
kiwi
orange
```

I need to get a list how many times each unique line occurred, eg.

```
4 kiwi
3 orange
2 onion
1 apple
```

Also line may contains special characters and digits.

Comment: Ok, you right, in common sense i meant that i need to compare lines and everything that may present in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a bunch of unix commands, in a pipeline:

```
$ sort sample| uniq -c | sort -nrk 1
   4 kiwi
   3 orange
   2 onion
   1 apple
```

If you need to limit the output, you can just use `head -n <<size>>` at the end of the line of commands.

Uniq needs the input file to be sorted, that's why I first call `sort` on the file named "sample". Afterward, we want the output ordered on the first column, by reverse numerical order.

Comment: Exactly what asked, simple and elegant way. Thanks for your help, Aif!